# Can I use rpm to expand the macros in a specfile?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

The concrete example being I have lots of specfiles with `Source0`: or other `Source` lines containing macros. How can I have these macros expanded without actually starting a build on the specfile or writing my own parser?

Comment: Did you ever get a better answer to this? I would like to expand all the macros in a spec file to show approximately how the script will look before it get's parsed in the next step.

Comment: You'd think that `rpmspec -E` would do what you want, but it doesn't seem to eval the macro in the specfile context. Insane.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You could grep to get the Source lines, sed to extract the string containing the macro and then rpm --eval 'string' to evaluate it. Note that this will only expand the global macros, not the ones defined in this spec.

To expand those as well you'd probably need to grep for them and feed them to rpm as your custom macros file.

Comment: Usually the urls contain at leas `%{version}` which does not get expanded (rpm 4.10.1)

Comment: This is actively wrong: https://wiki.merproject.org/wiki/Packaging_guidelines/ParsingSpecFiles

Answer (score 40):

Since rpm 4.9 you can use:

```
rpmspec -P <spec_file>
```

This will print out expanded spec file on stdout

Comment: This would be awesome, if only it would be available in current enterprise distributions (RHEL/CentOS).

Comment: rpm 4.10.1- this fails and requires the sources to be downloaded ahead, which renders it pretty useless. Can anyone confirm that (rule out a borked setup).

Comment: To clarify @Guss's comment, `rpmspec` is available on RHEL/CentOS 7 but not on RHEL/CentOS 6 or earlier.

Answer (score 12):

If its only the source lines you need parsed, `spectool` will do that for you. It's part of Fedora's [rpmdevtools](https://fedorahosted.org/rpmdevtools/).

```
$ spectool ./mg.spec 
Source0: http://homepage.boetes.org/software/mg/mg-20110120.tar.gz
$
```

Here's its help screen

```
Usage: spectool [<options>] <specfile>
Options:
operating mode:
-l, --lf, --list-files        lists the expanded sources/patches (default)
-g, --gf, --get-files         gets the sources/patches that are listed with
                              a URL
-h, --help                    display this help screen

files on which to operate:
-A, --all                     all files, sources and patches (default)
-S, --sources                 all sources
-P, --patches                 all patches
-s, --source x[,y[,...]]      specified sources
-p, --patch a[,b[,...]]       specified patches

misc:
-d, --define 'macro value'    defines RPM macro 'macro' to be 'value'
-C, --directory dir           download into specified directory (default '.')
-R, --sourcedir               download into rpm's %{_sourcedir}
-n, --dryrun, --dry-run       don't download anything, just show what would be
                              done
-D, --debug                   output debug info, don't clean up when done
```

Comment: This is the recommended option to extract and evaluate source files for most RPM based distribution.

Comment: Indeed this is a better way to handle SourceX lines then my solution (which is more generic on the other hand)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `/usr/bin/spectool` script in rpmdevtools that @mmckinst talks about, you'll see it's just an elaborate hack. It creates a tmp spec file that essentially does what script below does. This is what we're using to expand the spec file and then grep for the parts of the file we need. In our case, we wanted more than the sources and patches.

Here's a sample bash script that simulates this behavior. It will expand all macros up through the `%prep` section.

```
#!/bin/bash
spec_file="$1" # pass in the path to the spec file as the first argument
tmp_spec="/tmp/eval-$$.spec"
cat "$spec_file" | sed '/^%prep/,$d' > "$tmp_spec"
echo '%prep' >> "$tmp_spec"
echo 'cat<<__EOF__' >> $tmp_spec
cat "$spec_file" | sed '/^%prep/,$d' >> "$tmp_spec"
echo '__EOF__' >> "$tmp_spec"
rpmbuild -bp "$tmp_spec" 2>/dev/null
rm -f "$tmp_spec"
```

Comment: This is indeed a useful workaround when `spectool` is not available on your machine.

Comment: I tried the script without success (it returned an exit code of 0 without printing anything); I think it's interesting but the "--nodeps" option should be added to rpmbuild (otherwise an unsatisfied BuildRequires will prevent rpmbuild from working), and an explicit message and exit code should be propagated in the event rpmbuild fails. I'm proposing an edit to the post with such changes.

Answer (score 1):

### Expand macros in scripts

If you're interested in what the scripts in your RPM look like after macro expansion, you can just build the RPM and then get RPM to extract the scripts:

```
rpmbuild -bi my-package.spec
rpm -qp --scripts my-package.rpm
```

This works because RPM expands the macros at build-time.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote that parser in Python :)

https://github.com/packit/specfile/

```
$ python3 -c 'import specfile; print(specfile.Specfile("units.spec").expand("%version"))'
2.21
```